# Email functionality in SP 2013 library not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, email, library

Although I have set one of my libraries to receive email, set up the email address, save all attachments in root folder, and accept emails from any sender, I still can't see any emails in the library.  What else do I need to check or activate in order to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps are the following:

1. Install and configure SMTP service on SharePoint.
2. Configure incoming E-Mail settings in SharePoint Central Administration.
3. Add a Send connector in Exchange Server.
4. Configure library incoming email settings.

You could check this article to Configure Incoming E-mail in SharePoint 2013:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ccaa4ae4-65a7-4d9b-aedc-c64f40ed0dc0/forum-faqhow-to-configure-incoming-email-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointadmin